# Simcity-buildit: Where do gifts appear in neighboring cities

Tags: simcity-buildit

When one visits a neighbor to trade, every now and then you get a gift. Do they appear anywhere on the map, or close to Global Trade HQ ? I don't want to have to search the entire town for that reward which seems to appear in average every 10 visits or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gifts show up completely at random, and in completely random locations. However, they only appear above residential buildings, so you don't have to check above services buildings or specializations buildings.